# Local to remote proxy through UDP

Tags: proxy, udp, tunnel

I'm trying to solve a very specific problem that requires me to have a proxy that has two components (local and remote) and a tunnel in between. The tunnel reads and writes to UDP ports, best if different ones for each direction.

The local proxy would receive the connection requests and would then forward them to the remote proxy, that will then do the actual proxying towards the end destination.

Connection -> Local proxy -> UDP A -> Remote proxy -> Internet -> destination
and then back
Response -> Internet -> Remote proxy -> UDP B -> local proxy -> destination

Is there any proxy that allows to have this scenario? The closest I've found is Gost, but it doesn't really allow complete tunnelling over UDP.